# Working with time intervals in data logging?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I'm programming a data logging application. I need to be able to store a time interval typed in by the user using `Core Data`. For instance, if the user completes a task in seven minutes and twenty-three seconds, he/she can type `7:28` into the `NSTextField` and that will be part of the data.

What class should I use to store the time? `NSDate` seems to be the right way of doing it, but it does not seem to store time intervals. I see that there is an `NSTimeInterval` class. However, with no particular reference for it, I do not know how to use it.

Also, when this time interval is stored in objects within Core Data, I need to be able to retrieve those items and sort them (using `NSSortDescriptor`); in order to retrieve the entry that logged the lowest time interval. This is just additional information to help figure out what I need to do here.

Answer (score 1):

If the user types in 7:28, could you convert this into seconds (448 seconds) and store it in a NSUInteger? That would make sorting it easily because you would not have to deal with separate minute and second values.

Here's what I think you should do:

- Have two fields for user input: one for minutes and one for seconds.
- Have some code like this:

  `NSInteger totalTime1 = 0;`

  `totalTime += [minuteField.text integerValue]*60;`

  `totalTime += [secondField.text integerValue];`

Now store `totalTime1` using Core Data. To retrieve the times and sort them, do something like this:

```
//Retrive times
NSArray *retrievedTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: time1FromCoreDataAsNSNumber, time2FromCoreDataAsNSNumber, etc, nil];
NSArray *sortedRetrievedTimes = [retrievedTimes sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

//Now the array is sorted from lowest to highest
NSInteger lowestValue = [[sortedRetrievedTimes objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Late last night I came to somewhat the same solution, and it's good to hear that's the right way to go.

Comment: @TopherHoward Remember to mark it as the answer if it helped in order to help future site visitors find a solution to similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: `NSDate` objects represent a single point in time.

From your use case it sounds like you want the user to log a *relative* time, and then to be able to sort by which is the smallest.  In that case, NSDate is not a good option.  The best solution is to just store the time interval as an NSUInteger, where the integer represents your value in seconds, and then do the appropriate conversions on either end.